# wxPython: ListBox not selectable/clickable when used with ComboCtrl

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython

I am trying to couple `wx.ListBox` with `wx.combo.Comboctrl`. A sample code is below. For some reason, the items in the ListBox are not clickable/selectable. I wonder how I can make it work. Thanks!

### EDIT: Missing code added

```
import wx, wx.combo

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="", size=(300, 100))
        gbs = wx.GridBagSizer()
        ComboCtrlBox = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self)
        ComboCtrlPopup = ListBoxComboPopup()
        ComboCtrlBox.SetPopupControl(ComboCtrlPopup)
        ComboCtrlPopup.ListBox.Append("Apple")
        ComboCtrlPopup.ListBox.Append("Banana")
        ComboCtrlPopup.ListBox.Append("Orange")

        ComboCtrlPopup.ListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelect) #ADDED

        gbs.Add(ComboCtrlBox, pos = (0, 0), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border = 10)
        gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)
        self.SetSizer(gbs)
        self.Layout()

    def OnSelect(self, evt):    #ADDED
        print "HAHA"

   
class ListBoxComboPopup(wx.combo.ComboPopup):
    def Init(self):
        self.ItemList = []
    
    def Create(self, parent):
        self.ListBox = wx.ListBox(parent, -1, size = (-1, 20), choices = self.ItemList)
    
    def GetControl(self):
        return self.ListBox
    
    def OnPopup(self):
        pass

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = wx.App(False)
    FRAME = MainFrame(None)
    FRAME.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things in your `ListBoxComboPopup` class needed to make it work well with the `ComboCtrl`. At a minimum you are missing some event binding and handler to catch selection events from the `ListBox`, and an implementation of the `GetStringValue` method which the combo will call to get the value to be displayed.  Please see the `ComboCtrl` sample in the wxPython demo for more details and example code.

Comment: The issue right now is that the items in the `ListBox` popup won't even highlight when I try to click on them. With regular list boxes (e.g., when they are by themselves and not combined with `ComboCtrl`) even if I don't add any event binding, if I click on an item, it will be highlighted.

Comment: Platform and version of wxPython?

Comment: 64 bit Windows 7, Python 2.7.11 (came with Enthought Canopy), and wx version 2.8.10.1

Comment: Canopy has wxPython 3.0.2.0 available now, I recommend that you update to that version (run `enpkg wxpython`). However it still has a problem with this sample when it should be working as it does on other platforms... I'll dig into it a little later when I have some time to try to find out what is going on. Meanwhile, it does work with a `wx.ListCtrl` as demonstrated in the wxPython demo.